# Alternative to google API (e.g. jquery) for charting w/o privacy concerns

Tags: python, web-development, django

Having read this post : [Privacy risk in using Google APIs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38415/privacy-risk-in-using-google-apis), I am wondering what are the alternatives with no privacy concern, esp. for website charting development(e.g. chart.js)?

Comment: I would also be grateful anyone could point out a software can detect/scan those API, built JS library whether it has potential of privacy threats. (e.g. malware/Adware-like)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [RGraph](https://www.rgraph.net/) to make custom charts. I consider RGraph an undervalued tool, with tons of options and details. By default is not very nice, but if you just mimic the Google Chart colors and tinker a bit, your graphs become "cute and good enough". Also, lots of demos, examples and good documentation.

Comment: Thanks! First time heard this. Looks promising. incl. interactive SVG charting? How do we know whether it has e.g. any google API linked or embedded? (PS: sorry I would like to upvote but I need at least 15 points :-(

Comment: I think it has no Google API bindings, but you can use ajax and csv if I recall well